# SVG Image in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In the year 2018, what is the best way to load an SVG and place it in an Android layout. The SVG is going to be downloaded from the internet, by the app. Bundling will not take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glide library.

Sample example for glide [example](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.6.0)

For svg image you have to create a Setup RequestBuilder

```
requestBuilder = Glide.with(mActivity)
.using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, mActivity), InputStream.class)
.from(Uri.class)
.as(SVG.class)
.transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
.sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
.cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SvgDecoder()))
.decoder(new SvgDecoder())
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_facebook)
.error(R.drawable.ic_web)
.animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
.listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());
```

Use RequestBuilder with uri

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg");
requestBuilder
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
// SVG cannot be serialized so it's not worth to cache it
.load(uri)
.into(mImageView);
```

hope this is helpful